# How use a separator like " "," "

Tags: r, import, delimiter

I have a problem. 
I need to import data in R but the separator is `","`.

Not just a comma but a comma surrounded by two quote.
But if I put it as a separator I have the command:

```
"DownloadFormat"="","".
```

And r does not understand. How can I protect this separator?

Comment: `"\",\""` should do the trick

Comment: Did will try; "DownloadFormat"='","'

Comment: Ok just perfect. Thanks

Comment: That is a very weird separator. Are you sure the separator isn’t just a comma, and the values are quoted?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes it's really "," and i don't choose... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *@G.Grothendieck's* example [hugo.dat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55003053/680068) file, we can add missing quotes, and read as CSV:

```
read.csv(textConnection(paste0('"', readLines("hugo.dat"), '"')))

#    a  b  c  d
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) readLines/gsub** Questions to SO on R should include a complete verifiable example.  Without such we provide our own in the Note at the end.  The code may need to be modified depending on the actual data.  First read the data line by line using `readLines` and remove all double quotes.  Then re-read it using `read.csv`.

```
L <- gsub('"', '', readLines("hugo.dat"))
DF <- read.csv(text = L)
DF
```

giving:

```
   a  b  c  d
1  1  2  3  4
2 13 14 15 16
```

**2) pipe/sed** Another possibility is the one-liner:

```
read.csv(pipe("sed -e 's/\"//g' hugo.dat"))
```

On Windows be sure that you have Rtools installed and that C:\Rtools\bin is on your Windows PATH (assuming the default Rtools installation directory).  Although this worked for me on both straight Windows and on Linux using bash you might need to modify it slightly depending on what shell you use due to differences in how different shells deal with escaping and quoting.

### Note

```
Lines <- 'a","b","c","d
1","2","3","4
13","14","15","16'
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "hugo.dat")
```